# Edit UITableView cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have three viewControllers.
One which displays a UITableView.
The other where I can add objects to the UITableView
and one where I can edit the objects in the UITableView.

I have successfully been able to populate the UITableView with items and transfer the date in the cell to the edit view controller, but my question is.

After I've edited the data from the cell in my edit viewController, how do I pass the edited text back and apply it to the cell it came from.

I am using `prepareForSegue` to send the text from a selected cell to the edit view controller and that all works fine but now how do I transfer the edited version back to the same cell it came from?

Comment: Are you using a model here? And is it a subclass of `NSObject` or something else?

Comment: Sorry for not including that. I'm subclassing NSObject, I have an instance called Tasks which I store an array from the save view controller.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a protocol to do this. The edit view controller should define a protocol, and the table view controller would set itself as delegate in prepareForSegue. When you're done editing, call the delegate method with the new data, and have the table view controller update its model with that new data, then reload the table view (the table view controller would have to keep a pointer to the indexPath of the cell whose data you passed to the edit controller so it would know which item in the data source to update). Using a protocol is pretty standard practice for sending data back to a previous controller.